# Linear program solved with Simplex out of given bound

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, simplex

I believe to be missing something important in the Simplex algorithm because it goes beyond the given objective.

Let be the following linear programming program:

\begin{cases}
\max Z(x,y,z)=&x&+y&+z&\\
& x& & &\le 10\\
&-3x&-\frac{1}{4}y&+z&\le 4\\
&&y& &\le 20\\
&& & z&\le 40\\
 & & &x,y,z&\ge0
\end{cases}

I wanted to solve it with the matrix method knowing that the given optimal value is $69$.

**I don't know how to find the origin starting point, and I would be glad if you can provide me a method**, but I had:

\begin{cases}
e_1=10\\
e_2=4\\
e_3=20\\
e_4=40
\end{cases}

given as a starting point. **I don't know what to do with it.**

At the beginning $y$ enters the basis and $e_2$ goes out.

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &10\\ 
-12 & 1 & 4 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 16\\
12 & 0 & -4 & 0 & -4 & 1 & 0 & 4\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 40\\
13 & 0 & 5 & 0 & -4 & 0 & 0 & -16\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
e_1\\y\\e_3\\e_4
\end{pmatrix}$$

$x$ enters the basis and $e_3$ goes out.

\begin{cases}
L_2=L_2+12L_1\\
L_3=L_3-12L_1\\
L_5=L_5-13L_1
\end{cases}

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &10\\ 
0 & 1 & 4 & 12 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 136\\
12 & 0 & -4 & 0 & -4 & 1 & 0 & -116\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 40\\
0 & 0 & 5 & -13 & -4 & 0 & 0 & -146\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
e_1\\y\\x\\e_4
\end{pmatrix}$$

Yet, here, there is something wrong: I'm already maximizing at a level of $146$ when the given maximum is only $69$.

**What did I missed in applying the Simplex algorithm matricial method?**

The scilab operation to obtain $69$ are

```
M=PIVOTGJ(M,1,1)
M=PIVOTGJ(M,2,3)
M=PIVOTGJ(M,3,2)
```

and the given optimal solution is $x=10, y=10, z=39, e_4=1$

Comment: i think your solution is not feasible, so the max value of $146$ is ok -- it can be more if it does not satisfy the constraints.

Comment: The given optimal solution is correct.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks for checking, therefore where did I went wrong?

Comment: No idea ! It has been almost 50 years I did not use the simplex method. Sorry for that ! By the way, where are you located in France ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Never mind! Paris Dauphine University!